# android javascript regex detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html

How would I create 3 more scripts with regex that would check if the android is a certain version. I provided a sample ua header from a android version 2.2.

scripts needed

- android 2.2.3 and below check
- android 2.3 to 2.3.7 check
- android 3.0 and above check

android ua string example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1     (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

based off of this script

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, how about something like this:

```
var isAndroid = /android/i.test(ua);
var isGingerbread = /android 2\.3/i.test(ua);
var isHoneycombOrNewer = /android [3-9]/i.test(ua);
var isFroyoOrOlder = isAndroid && !isGingerbread && !isHoneycombOrNewer;
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I just realized you were doing indexOf instead of actual regex.  Let me update my answer.